# how to check the element of array in golang when debug

Tags: debugging, go

my environment is ubuntu 16.04+eclipse neon3+goeclipse

this is my source code:

```
package main
import  "fmt"

func main() {
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

it is very simple and I just want to know how to check the element of array **arr** when debug if I set breakPoint at **println**.when I check **arr** this is what I get [image].As we can see I cant get the element of **arr** and only can get the *address* of **arr**. And it has two errors: 
`Failed to execute MI command:-data-evaluate-expression (arr).len Error message from debugger back end:A syntax error in expression, near 'len'.`
 It seemed the error has relation with gdb but I dont know how to get rid of it.
In java,as for similar code.

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = {1,2,3};
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```

it is easy to get the element of arr when debug.[image]

So I want to know how can I get the element of array in Go when debug and how can I get rid of the error when debug. Any advice will be appreciate.

Comment: Did you try gogland?

Comment: @mattn yeah,gogland meet my requirements.